# Porting EntityFrameworks on Mono status

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, mono

I know the entity frameworks are still not ported to mono.

I would like to know the current status (since on the mono site I dont see anything of an update)
I would like to know if they want to port it, when they would start on it and when I would expect it to be their.

Also I like to know if their are other open source libraries out their that have the same functions as the Entity Framework and maybe would go on mono.

I found an framework that is called [Entify](http://www.taimila.com/entify/features.php).
Although I looks like their is no support for the bigger databases.

Comment: Today Microsoft has announced EF will be a Free Source Code, perhaps this will start the adoption to Mono

Answer (score 5):

Here is the latest official word from the Mono team:

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2010-October/036135.html

To summarize, there are no plans for Mono to write EF.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mono-project.com/Database_Access

Doesn't [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET) do what you want?

Comment: No, it's still active project with many users ( http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx ).

Comment: As far as I know, NHibernate is still in use well around the world. Even enterprise solutions are there using it. So EF is not that necessary, if Mono team need to focus on MonoMac or other promising fields.

Comment: Ya, Nhibernate came to the rescue. I ported the EF to Nhibernate.