# Mono + Entity Framework using MS DLL?

Tags: entity-framework, mono

I know Mono has no EF implementation, and no plans to create one.

Would it be possible, however, to simply take the relevant DLLs from .NET and add them into my Mono project in MonoDevelop? I may be completely misunderstanding how this is supposed to work; but wondered if this would then allow me to continue using EF + Mono rather than replacing the ORM.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: To save having to redevelop the ORM/Model code right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [Entity Framework on Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223258/porting-entityframeworks-on-mono-status) status, see the [mailing list post](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2010-October/036135.html).

For the legal status, see [Entity Framework license agreement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896268.aspx). You are licensed to run Microsoft .Net on any legal copy of Windows, not on other operating systems. So even if this was technically possible, it would not solve your business problem. If you think now "what about ASP.NET MVC?" or something like that - those products are released by a different team and come with another license agreement that is much less restricted.

Comment: Thank you. We'll just have to take another approach.

Answer (score 2):

Since version [2.11.3](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Aug-13.html) mono includes entity framework functionality.